# React-router-dom v6 nested routes only render the top level route and none of the nested

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I've been working with `react-router-rom` v6 for a little while now and was experimenting with nested routes. I had experience doing this in v5 without problem. I have followed some tutorials and looked up examples how to properly do nested routes in v6, but can't seem to understand what I may be missing.

Below is a portion of the nested route. When I navigate to `"/users"`, it renders the `Users` component without issue. When I navigate to the `"/users/invite"` it still only ever renders the `Users` component.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path='users' element={<Users />}>
    <Route path='invite' element={<Invite />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

From what I understand, navigating to `"/users"` should render the `Users` component and navigating to `"/users/invite"` should render the `Invite` component since it's nested inside of the `<Route/>` component.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `Users` and `Invite` to be matched and rendered independently then one can't be nested within the other. Render them as sibling routes.

Example:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/users" element={<Users />} />
  <Route path="/users/invite" element={<Invite />} />
</Routes>
```

or

```
<Routes>
  <Route path='/users'>
    <Route index element={<Users />} />
    <Route path="invite" element={<Invite />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

If you do actually want `Users` to be rendered as part of a layout when the path is `"/users/invite"` then `Users` necessarily should render an `Outlet` component for nested routes to render their `element` content into.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const Users = () => {
  ...

  return (
    ...

    <Outlet /> // <-- nested route content rendered here
    ...
  );
};
```

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/users" element={<Users />}>
    <Route path="invite" element={<Invite />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Answer (score 0):

The  component is where the child route component will be rendered, so you need to include it in your parent route component. For example, in your Users component, you need to do like this:

```
function Users() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Users</h1>
      <Link to="invite">Invite a user</Link>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}
```